# Image Not uploading in base64 format using retrofit

Tags: java, android, retrofit2

I Am uploading an image which I convert into base64 , and try to send image into server, using Retrofit Library, but problem is that, Sometime Image Are Uploading successfully but sometime its going on on Failure() method in Retrofit , and throwing the error is **timeout**  , I don't know what is the problem with that , sometime its working or sometime its not working, I am also trying to increase the time using http but still having the Same problem.

Answer (score 1):

The description you gave is a little bit vague. Could you share more info? What type of file are you trying to upload? The size of the files that are failing vs the ones that are succeeding the upload. Mind that if you base64 encode the contents of an mage it ends up being about 33% bigger and server might be closing connections that last longer than say 5 seconds ending up in timeouts. Please share some logs and stack-traces alongisde the metadata of the files you're uploading :) Probably you can fix this problem server-side by extending the TTL before a timeout's thrown

Comment: My problem is that I am uploading a base64 image using retrofit library , its working all day but in some time its throwing the error in on Failure() method , my image size is  1 to 2 MB , If its not working today then it will work on next for long  days , and then its throwing the same error

Comment: OkHttpClient client = new OkHttpClient.Builder()
                .connectTimeout(90000, TimeUnit.SECONDS)
                .readTimeout(90000, TimeUnit.SECONDS).build();

        Retrofit retrofit = new Retrofit.Builder()
                .baseUrl(Share_Data.BASE_URL).client(client)
                .addConverterFactory(GsonConverterFactory.create())
                .build();

        Api request = retrofit.create(Api.class)

Comment: A TCP connection can be closed by either peer of the connection. What you're configuring here on the `connectTimeout` is how much time has to pass from your peer (the android phone) before the phone cancels the connection. In this case that is 250h. On the serverside they also have these kind of settings. Most of the times hidden behind some defaults. Because I don't expect you to have waited 250h before receiving a timeout I'd insist on sitting down with your backender and troubleshooting the problem together

Comment: It should go without saying that file-size constraints are also taken in account but you'd get a `400` error from the backend rather than a timeout. I think it's safe to assume there is no problem there I assume

Comment: but if server side does not have problem then , my code should not running single time , that is the question

Comment: its happening only sometimes in a weak

Comment: Yeah. Repeat the same test with the same image and get proof of same code with same image failing and succeeding and ask your teammate to help you troubleshoot that. If your code was wrong it wouldn't work a single time :)

Answer (score 0):

Try to use OKHttp, it's more robust, here a link that can help you:
[OKHttp](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/okhttp-android-example-tutorial)

Comment: its ok but may i know what is the problem with retrofit

Comment: did you check this post ? it might help you https://howtodoinjava.com/retrofit2/connection-timeout-exception/

Comment: I write the same code for testing but still same issue , its happening if its did not work today then it will work for next 5 to 6 days and then its throwing the error again. that's why i did not understand what's the error , if my code is wrong then why its worked sometime

Comment: Perhaps your connexion get low when you test or something like this, did you check your timeOut in postMan ?

Comment: yes i checked its upto only 9 to 12 sec

Comment: it's probably because of bad connexion

Comment: but i am having a strong 5G connection

Comment: Try to set you setTimeOut to 15 or 20 sec, and keep testing if the problem persist

Comment: .connectTimeout(90000, TimeUnit.SECONDS)
                .readTimeout(90000, TimeUnit.SECONDS).build();

Comment: Already give it

Comment: SO i have no idead where is the problem, please if you find the core problem or a solution, share it with us